# SPARQL Query : How to filter xsd:dateTime by time?

Tags: filter, sparql, rdf, ontology

I dont really find anything online , that is why I'm asking here. I have the following query :

> "return all the people that prefer to depart in the morning"

myns is my PREFIX of my ontology in Protedge. Here is what I wrote so far :

```
SELECT ?person  
WHERE {     
?person myns:bookTicket     ?ticket.    
?ticket myns:hasFligth      ?fligth.    
?fligth myns:hasDepartureTime   ?time.  
FILTER ( how to return ?time that depart in the morning so < 1pm ) 
}
```

**Here myns:hasDepartureTime returns an xsd:dateTime type** (**E.G "2022-05-04T22:00:00"**). I know how to filter by Date but I dont really know how to extract the time so I can filter it by Time. I need to return all the fligths that depart in the morning so I can accomplish my goal. Because no matter which time I use , the FILTER will always look at the day first, and I dont care about which day the fligth departs but only its time.

Comment: the only native way is to use `hours` and `minutes` functions on the `xsd:dateTime` literal in your filter

Comment: I used the hours function as FILTER( hours(?time) < 13) but it gives me back an error : org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Unknown function 'w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#hours-from-dateTime'

Answer (score 1):

> but I dont really know how to extract the time so I can filter it by Time.

As [UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022614/sparql-query-how-to-filter-xsddatetime-by-time#comment128973228_73022614):

> use hours and minutes functions on the xsd:dateTime literal in your filter

For example:

```
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?dt {
 values ?dt {
    "2022-07-18T10:06:41.756+00:00"^^xsd:dateTime
    "2022-07-18T17:06:41.756+00:00"^^xsd:dateTime
    "2022-07-18T14:06:41.756+00:00"^^xsd:dateTime
    "2022-07-18T08:06:41.756+00:00"^^xsd:dateTime
  }

  filter ( hours(?dt) < 13 )
}
```

Comment: With this filter it tells me : org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Unknown function 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#hours-from-dateTime'. I dont know why is like he does not know the hours function.

Comment: @alitoccacieli [hours](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-hours) is a standard SPARQL 1.1 function.  What endpoint are you using? Does it support SPARQL 1.1?

Comment: Im using protégé on MacOs , i dont know which version I do have. This is the prefixes I use :
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>